# PHP: Infinite session

Tags: php, session, localhost

I have a WAMP server installed locally and developing some small project. I've added an authorization page with sessions. 
All the PHP settings on my localhost are default, so it means that `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`, so it equals to 24 minutes. But the problem is that this session does not end. Never. 
I tried to change that setting to 60 seconds, or even 600 seconds, but it is infinite anyway.

Can you, please, explain me, is it a problem or I have just forgotten to change some other settings?

P.S. I know I have to restart server to completely change settings.

Comment: Check your `php.ini` settings for [session params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: I change this setting in php.ini directly. What exactly should I check?
I've read somewhere now that session maxlifetime is the expiration time of the session regardless of activity or inactivity. I thought that it will only be destroyed after some period of inactivity...

Comment: Did you change the correct *php.ini*?

Comment: Yes: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin;
That where the WAMP's Apache is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation....

> **session.cookie_lifetime** specifies the lifetime of the cookie in
>   seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the
>   browser is closed." Defaults to 0. See also
>   session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

Comment: It is set to 0 by default - I did not change it. But the session still not destroyed after I restarted browser. :( I know I do something wrong, but I can not figure out what exactly